# Checking for "rEVERSE cAPS lOCK" on a string

Tags: php

We've been getting a number of spam form submissions recently, and the common denominator in them all is that they seem to be written by someone who has their caps lock key stuck on (or at least has a very chaotic use of it). The defining characteristics is that the first character is always lowercase, and the last two characters are always uppercase. Those in the middle may be either.

> e.g. "hELLO" or "helLO"

How would I go about checking if a string meets this criteria? This is what I have so far:

```
if (strlen($x) > 3) {
    if ((preg_match('/[A-Z]+/', substr($x), -2, 2) === 1) &&
         preg_match('/[a-z]/', substr($x, 1) === 1)) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

But that doesn't seem to be working (or particularly efficient).

Comment: Something like `/^[a-z]{1}.*[A-Z]{2}$/` ... though you might be better off sticking a CAPTCHA on the form.

Comment: tHIS IS NOT NECESSARY A SPAM> tHIS CAN BE SOMEONE WHO FORGOT OR DIDN"T NOTICE THE CAPSLOCK> aS STATED @CD001 A captcha IS CERTAINLY A BETTER SOLUTION TO AVOID REMOVING NON SPAM

Comment: I'm building a tool where we just flag potential spam submissions according to a handful of rules. Everything will always be manually checked before any destructive operations are performed. And we can't use a captcha because Google doesn't work in China. :)

Comment: You know what's really efficient? Scouring StackOverflow for people who want to use sketchy solutions and then abuse those solutions. Really, the problem  here is that everyone can submit your form with whatever contents they want. The problem isn't the form handling; which is what you are changing. What if the spammer knew your tactics and just changed his rules? Slap a captcha or some other form of client-side validation to your form..! There's loads of alternatives to Google's :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this regex here to detect words that fit your parameters of starting with a lower case char and ending in two upper case ones.

`/[a-z][A-Za-z]*[A-Z]{2}/`

https://regexr.com/463fk

As pointed out in the comments though - this could be a legitimate mistake so I'd recommend not to simply block the input because of it but rather present the user with an appropriate error message.

That aside implementing a honeypot or a captcha should be more effective at preventing spam submissions - personally I tend to try a honeypot before going for the more intrusive captcha solution.